# Connect to Postgres via AWS Glue Python script

Tags: aws-glue

Going through the AWS Glue docs I can't see any mention of how to connect to a Postgres RDS via a Glue job of "Python shell" type.  I've set up a RDS connection in AWS Glue and verified I can connect to my RDS.  Also, when creating the Python job I can see my connection and I've added it to the script.

How do I use the connection which I've added to the Glue job to run some raw SQL?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you have any luck with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to access data from RDS in glue etl (spark):

**1st Option**:

- Create a glue connection on top of RDS
- Create a glue crawler on top of this glue connection created in first step
- Run the crawler to populate the glue catalogue with database and table pointing to RDS tables.
- Create a dynamic frame in glue etl using the newly created database and table in glue catalogue.

Code Sample :

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="{{database}}", table_name="{{table_name}}")
```

**2nd Option**

Create a dataframe using spark sql :

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://<rds_host_name>/<database_name>"
properties = {
"user" : "<username>",
"password" : "<password>"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="<schema.table>", properties=properties)
```

Note :

- You will need to pass postgres jdbc jar for creating the database using spark sql.
- I have tried first method on glue etl and second method on python shell (dev-endpoint)

Comment: Want to be able to execute Raw SQL queries.  Such as `CREATE ...`.  In the above case that's not possible...from my understanding. :/

Comment: @Harsh "You will need to pass postgres jdbc jar for creating the database using spark sql." - how would I do this?

Comment: @t_warsop : You will need to ssh to end point, download the postgre jar and pass it with your spark-submit command. I couldn't figure out a better way for dev endpoints.

Comment: @mcm : you can use spark's sqlcontext to execute the CREATE command, sqlContext.sql(query).